# What are the "tails"?

Tags: fermentation, techniques

While reading an article on home brewing the article said to keep the tails, what does it mean by tails? What are the tails?

Comment: Can you post a quote where it is used? Without context - I have no idea.

Comment: Are you sure it was homebrewing and not an article related to distillation?

Comment: @brewchez that makes sense, but I can't figure a use for distillation tails, maybe as a fuel or solvent?

Comment: Can't find the article I read it on to save my life, I have gone through my search history but no luck, but Evil Zymurgist nailed the question.

Comment: I've heard the term used in moonshine distilling.  The tails is the last of the liquid you get from the distillation process. It's a mix of good ethanol and harmful  alcohols, so you don't want to drink it. However, it can be thrown into your next batch to boost the quantity of ethanol you get in your next batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tails or Tailings** *is what's left of a material after it has been processes and something more valuable has been removed. Though a term used in mining more than homebrewing.*

In brewing this will refer to making use of...

1) Second runnings from a mash, parti-gyle. Great for a second a batch of a smaller beer or for yeast starter wort.

2) Making use of spent grain for baking or compost

3) Yeast trub. The gunk on the bottom of the fermentor. This is mostly yeast, hops, etc. Use this to grow more yeast, or even pitch a seconds batch of wort right on top.

Comment: Yes using this in context with what I remember reading makes very good sense.